# Object Oriented Programming Difference between class & module

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to OOP and Python and not quit understanding the difference between Classes, Modules, Packages and Libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Modules usually contain Classes, They allow one to separate resources for purposes of logical organization.

See also

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_modules.htm

Other languages such as C# also use Modules

[What are classes and modules for in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168495/what-are-classes-and-modules-for-in-c-sharp)

There is also a concept in JavaScript

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/modules